# XMPPHP How to get all registered users list

Tags: php, xmpp

I am using XMPPHP code (https://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) for connecting XMPP (eJabberd) server. I have successfully connected with server and able to send message to another user using file called sendmessage_example.php

Now I want to run IQ query for getting all registered users list (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#get-registered-users-list) using XMPPHP code but not able to run IQ query.

I have created function in XMPP.PHP file

```
public function getAllRegisteredUsers(){
    print_r($this->send("<iq from='admin@example.com'
                        id='get-disabled-users-num-1'
                        to='example.com'
                        type='set'
                        xml:lang='en'>
                        <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' 
                               action='execute'
                               node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-registered-users-list'/>
                        </iq>"));

}
```

And calling from another test.php file **$conn->getAllRegisteredUsers();** but every time it returns some number **343 or 112 or 110**

**test.php code:**

```
include 'XMPPHP/XMPP.php';
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('IP address', 5222, 'admin@example.com', 'password', 'xmpphp', 'example.com', $printlog=false, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);
$conn->autoSubscribe();

try {

$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->presence($status='Controller available.');
$conn->processTime(2);

// now see the results
$conn->getAllRegisteredUsers();

} catch(XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```